# Extracting month,day and year in react with date.toLocaleString not working

Tags: reactjs, date, react-props

I am building a react app and i am trying to extract the month,day and year in react with date.toLocaleString and my website is crashing,showing a blank page, and it isn t showing my components.This should output the month(e.g august), the year (e.g 1967) and the day (e.g 15)[image]

```
function ExpenseDate(props) {
const month = props.date.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "long" });
const day = props.date.toLocaleString("en-US", { day: "2-digit" });
const year = props.date.getFullYear();
  return (
     <div>
      <div>{month}</div>
    <div>{day}</div>
    <div>{year}</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: any error on the dev console?

Answer (score 1):

did you call props in ExpenseItem(i suppose)? try doing this between div's .

```
<ExpenseDate date={props.date} />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I was going through the same course and ran into the same problem when I started splitting the components between ExpenseItem and ExpensDate.

What you need to do is:

- inside of the expenses array, have your date value be a string of a new date
  [image: App.js]
- then, pass that date string down into the ExpenseDate component as a prop
  [image: ExpenseItem.js]
- finally, use that date string inside the ExpenseDate component to display a new date each time the ExpenseDate component is rendered.
  [image: ExpenseDate.js]
- this is what it will look like with different dates being rendered in each ExpensDate component
  [image]

I hope this helps you or the next guy that runs into that problem taking the course.

Answer (score 1):

**I solved it using this way, by adding the states into one object and not changing date**

ExpenseFrom.js code below:

```
import "./ExpenseForm.css";
import { useState } from "react";

const ExpenseForm = (props) => {
  // const [enteredTitle, setEnteredTitle] = useState("");
  // const [enteredAmount, setEnteredAmount] = useState("");
  // const [enteredDate, setEnteredDate] = useState("");

  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState({
    title: "",
    amount: "",
    date: "",
  });

  const TitleChangeHandler = (event) => {
    // setEnteredTitle(event.target.value);
    setUserInput((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        title: event.target.value
      };
    });
  };

  const AmountChangeHandler = (event) => {
    // setEnteredAmount(event.target.value);
    setUserInput((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        amount: +event.target.value,
      };
    });
  };

  const DateChangeHandler = (event) => {
    // setEnteredDate(event.target.value);
    setUserInput((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...prevState,
        date: new Date(event.target.value),
      };
    });
  };

  const FormHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const FormData = userInput;
    props.onSaveExpenseData(FormData);
    //  props.onSaveExpenseData(event.userInput);

    // setEnteredTitle("");
    // setEnteredAmount("");
    // setEnteredDate("");

    setUserInput({});
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={FormHandler}>
      <div className="new-expense__controls">
        <div className="new-expense__control">
          <label>Title</label>
          <input type="text" onChange={TitleChangeHandler} />
        </div>
        <div className="new-expense__control">
          <label>Amount</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            min="0.01"
            step="0.01"
            onChange={AmountChangeHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="new-expense__control">
          <label>Date</label>
          <input
            type="date"
            min="2019-01-01"
            max="2023-01-01"
            onChange={DateChangeHandler}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="new-expense__action">
          <button type="button" onClick={props.onCancel}>
            Cancel
          </button>
          <button type="submit">Add Expense</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ExpenseForm;
```

ExpenseDate.js code below:

```
import "./ExpenseDate.css";

function ExpenseDate(props) {
    // const month = props.date?.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "long" });
    // const day = props.date?.toLocaleString("en-US", { day: "2-digit" });
    // const year = props.date?.getFullYear();

    const month = props.date.toLocaleString("en-us", { month: "long" });
    const day = props.date.toLocaleString("en-us", { day: "2-digit" });
    const year = props.date.getFullYear();

    return (
        <div className="expense-date">
        <div className="expense-date__month">{month}</div>
        <div className="expense-date__year">{year}</div>
        <div className="expense-date__day">{day}</div>
      </div>
    );
}

export default ExpenseDate;
```

I think this might work, no need to change the date, the problem was in passing the props.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in  React course. I just replaced the US time zone with another time zone, and it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change the date in expenses object (in App.js) toLocalString() because you cannot call date object methods on date again (as your are doing in ExpenseItem.js...